# PHP + MySQL: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

Until now I had in the DB table approximately 7500 records. This evening I imported another 4000 records (which makes 10500 total records) and when I run the app, I am getting the MySQL error message

```
Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I thought that will be a problem in my app, but then I tried to run the query through PhpMyAdmin and I got the same error

```
#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I am facing with this error for the first time. I looked around and it looks that the problem is caused due the big query. Which could be possible, but with the current count of records (7500) in the table the query execution took about 1.2 second.
So, why another 4000 records causing this error? Any idea, how to fix that?

Also, the app is running on Hostgator server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Lost+connection+to+MySQL+server+during+query

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you exhaust one resource for the db session, such as memory, and mysql closes the connection.

Quote from [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html)

> "The largest possible packet that can be transmitted to or from a
>   MySQL 5.1 server or client is 1GB.
>
> When a MySQL client or the mysqld server receives a packet bigger than
>   max_allowed_packet bytes, it issues a Packet too large error and
>   closes the connection. With some clients, you may also get a Lost
>   connection to MySQL server during query error if the communication
>   packet is too large."

**Possible fix:**

Break the sql dump into parts, and do it a bit at a time.

Running “optimize table #tablename” command should fix this issue if the table is corrupted.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried removing the additional 4000 records and testing if you can still query the database?